# Placing a VectorPlot under a plot3d

Tags: plotting

I am attempting to place the vector plot for the function f(x,y)=x^2+y^2 underneath my graph of the function but I cannot figure out how to graph them together. This is my attempt, but I am sure where to go from here.

```
f[x_,y_]=x^2+y^2
P1=Plot3D[f[x,y],{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10},
ClippingStyle->Off,
AxesLabel->{x,y,z},
AxesOrigin->{0,0,0},
Boxed->False,
ColorFunction->"Rainbow"]
P2=Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3],InfinitePlane[{{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,0}}]},
AxesLabel->{x,y,z},
AxesOrigin->{0,0,0},
Boxed->False]
P3=VectorPlot[Evaluate@Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PlotLegends -> None]
Show[P1,P2,P3]
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, y_] = x^2 + y^2;

P1 = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
    ClippingStyle -> Off,
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
    Boxed -> False, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];

P3 = VectorPlot[
   Evaluate@Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
   PlotLegends -> None];

P2 = Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[Small], 
       (Cases[P3, {_LABColor, _Arrow}, Infinity] /. 
        {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, y, 0}), 
    Opacity[0.3], 
    InfinitePlane[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}]}, 
   AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
   Boxed -> False];

Show[P1, P2]
```

[image]